# Finding the 4th side of Trapezoid that makes its Area at Maximum

Tags: calculus

I was trying some couple of math problems just to kill time and I stumbled upon this question:

If three sides of a trapezoid are each 6 inches long, how long must the fourth side be if the area is a maximum?

My work:

I do know that the area of a trapezoid is $A=0.5h(b_1 + b_2).$ But I need to express $A$ in terms of single variable $x$. You know.....$A = f(x)$. I imagine the problem like this:

[image: Trapezoid]

The area of the trapezoid now is $$A = \frac{1}{2} (6) ((6+\sqrt {x^2 - 36})+6)$$

Then: $$A = 3(12 + \sqrt {x^2 -36})$$ $$A = 36 + 3\sqrt {x^2 -36}$$

Differentiating the above equation with respect to $x$, we get:

$$\frac{dA}{dx} = 0 + 3\left(\frac{1}{2} (x^2-36)^\frac{-1}{2} (2x)\right )$$

$$\frac{dA}{dx} = \frac{3x}{2(x^2-36)^\frac{1}{2}}$$

I set $\frac{dA}{dx}$ to be zero to get the value of fourth side of trapezoid that makes its area maximum.

$$0= \frac{3x}{2(x^2-36)^\frac{1}{2}}$$

I got $x = 0$, which essentially makes the trapezoid losing its fourth side.

How do you answer the above question?

Comment: In your figure the trapezoid only has two sides equal to 6.

Comment: @Leonhard Oh wait......the x on the trapezoid is 6? And I must look on the lower base and set it as x?

Comment: Yes, and it wont be right angled.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ajotatxe's answer, and replacing the $6$'s by $a$ to make the problem more general, decompose the base $x$ as $x=a \cos(\theta)+a+a \cos(\theta)$ and the total area will be given by $$A=\frac 12 a^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+a^2 \sin(\theta)+\frac 12 a^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=a^2\sin(\theta)\left(1+ \cos(\theta)\right)$$ So, differentiating with respect to $\theta$
$$A'=-\sin ^2(\theta)+\cos ^2(\theta)+\cos (\theta)=\cos (\theta)+\cos (2\theta)$$ $$A''=-\sin (\theta)-2 \sin (2 \theta)$$ The first derivative cancels when $\theta=\frac \pi 3$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a maximum.

Back to $x$, we then get $x=2a$ and a maximum area $A=\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}a^2$

Answer (score 1):

A trapezoid can't have two equal bases (it wolud be a parallelogram), So if it has three equal sides, two of them are the non-parallel sides. The trapezoid would be like this:

[image]